# Do most phones use high density displays?

Tags: retina-display

Where can I get stats for the UK / USA about how many phones have double density displays?

Im making a website and im wondering weather to use media queries to load normal and double density resolution images for different devices. Or I could just use the double density resolution images for everyone.

Most desktop users will have a fast enough connection not to notice the different (the images are just logos and icons), so if most phones are double density then I might aswell just serve the same images to everyone.

Comment: Off topic but there is another issue with just using retina images. They require background-size css which older browsers wont support.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the service you provide in your website, which in turn determines which type of users visit your pages. A simple solutions is to check similar websites (specially the famous ones) and see whether they provide different resolutions to different users.

Comment: Is there no where i can get general stats in the way that I can for desktop screen size and browser?

Comment: [You may check this out: http://sender11.typepad.com/sender11/2008/04/mobile-screen-s.html](http://sender11.typepad.com/sender11/2008/04/mobile-screen-s.html)